# Resolving service in parameterless constructor causes InvalidOperationException in Repository

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-view-controller

I have a custom SiteRole class that inherits RoleProvider. I inject the IUserService in the constructor in order to do a query to get all Roles.

It kept on throwing an error that the SiteRole class needed a parameterless constructor. So I ended up injecting the IUserService like this:

```
public SiteRole()
{
    _userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
}
```

Inside the class I override the GetRolesForUser function

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string nickname)
{
    return new string[] { _userService.GetRoleForUser(nickname) };
}
```

The UserService calls this LINQ query in the UserRepository (This line throws System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.')

```
public string GetRoleForUser(string nickname)
{
    return DbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Nickname == nickname).FirstOrDefault().Role.Name;
}
```

Any hints on how I can resolve this? You cannot inject dependencies to RoleProvider via constructor so I have to use DependencyResolver.Current.GetService().

Comment: How do you register the `DbContext`?

Comment: You need to construct dbContext somewhere. Seems you are referencing the base class directly. Context should either be injected into the Repo constructor or newed up when the Repo is created.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `SiteRole` class has a longer lifetime than the injected `IUserService`. You should check if it's really the source of issue and tune lifetimes of registered services with use of your DI container API. Here are some links for different containers: [Autofac](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/), [NInject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes), [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx), [Simple injector](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html).

And, probably, change your `SiteRole` type a bit — use a property to get alive `UserService` instead of field, with which the only instance is created at time of `SiteRole` instantiation.

```
public SiteRole()
{
    // this field should be removed
    // _userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
}

// this property should be used instead of field
private IUserService UserService 
{
    get { DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>(); }
}
```

Or in modern syntax

```
private IUserService UserService => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
```

But be careful and check that you won't get uncontrolled count of `UserService` instances created, if it's for example configured as instance per call in your DI container.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
virtual Owned<IUserService> ResolveUserService()
=> DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Owned<IUserService>>();
```

And call the service in the GetRolesForUser Method with a Using statement:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string nickname)
    {
        using(var userService = ResolveUserService())
        {
            return new string[] {userService.Value.GetRoleForUser(nickname) };

        }
    }
```

On a sidenote, DbContext is constructed in the RepositoryBase. I'm using the Generic Repository Pattern for my project.

```
 public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{

    #region properties

    private StoreEntities dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;

    protected IDbFactory DbFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected StoreEntities DbContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DbFactory.Init()); }
    }

    #endregion

    protected RepositoryBase(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        DbFactory = dbFactory;
        dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }


    #region Implementation of defaults

    public virtual void Add(T entity)...........
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but reading the `Autofac` docs for the `Owned` type, I'd say that you will get new instance of `UserService` on every method call, which uses`IUserService` (if you have other consumers than `GetRolesForUser`, of course). And this isn't the best thing, because the same instance of `UserService` could be reused for the same http request, i.e [per request lifetime scope](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-request) should be used actually.